# Display spinner during AJAX call when using fetch API

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch-api

In my project I am migrating to React and so not loading JQuery. Since I don't have JQuery anymore, for AJAX calls I am using fetch. With JQuery I can hook the start and end of AJAX calls so it's very easy to change the cursor to a spinner. I can't find similar hooks in fetch. Is there a way to do this other than changing it in each individual AJAX call?

Lots of Googling just kept finding answers about... JQuery.

Comment: The global hooks were a bad idea in jQuery, this hasn't stopped. Do the spinner for each individual request that *your* application is doing.

Comment: @Bergi Why are the global hooks a bad idea?

Comment: Because you might be using a library that does its own `fetch` requests, and you don't want to intercept them. Or you might want to migrate away from intercepting *all* your own requests. To increase maintainability, just write your own wrapper function that does handle the spinner, and then call it whereever you need to do a request with a spinner.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There you go, I think the code is pretty much self-explanatory:

```
// Store a copy of the fetch function
var _oldFetch = fetch; 

// Create our new version of the fetch function
window.fetch = function(){

    // Create hooks
    var fetchStart = new Event( 'fetchStart', { 'view': document, 'bubbles': true, 'cancelable': false } );
    var fetchEnd = new Event( 'fetchEnd', { 'view': document, 'bubbles': true, 'cancelable': false } );

    // Pass the supplied arguments to the real fetch function
    var fetchCall = _oldFetch.apply(this, arguments);

    // Trigger the fetchStart event
    document.dispatchEvent(fetchStart);

    fetchCall.then(function(){
        // Trigger the fetchEnd event
        document.dispatchEvent(fetchEnd);
    }).catch(function(){
        // Trigger the fetchEnd event
        document.dispatchEvent(fetchEnd);
    });

    return fetchCall;
};

document.addEventListener('fetchStart', function() {
    console.log("Show spinner");
});

document.addEventListener('fetchEnd', function() {
    console.log("Hide spinner");
});
```

Here's a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/4fxfcp7g/4/

Comment: Notice that the `fetchEnd` fires before the whole response body is loaded

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I had in mind, case of beer for you! Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped you! Just make sure to use the latest edit of my snippet.

Comment: @EtienneMartin the latest seems to be broken... A call to a rest endpoint terminates in an error "TypeError: Already read"

Comment: You're right, my bad. I reverted to the previous version.

Answer (score 2):

Fetch in thenable, you can add spinner stop function in then(), that is called after response is received. And wrap it in another function for headers and hooking.

```
function ajax(someUrl, method) {
    var myHeaders = new Headers();

    var myInit = { 
        method: method,
        headers: myHeaders
    };
    showSpinner();

    return fetch(someUrl, myInit).then(function(response) {
        //... do some with response
        hideSpinner();

        return response;
    }).catch(function(error) {
        //... tell the user the request failed and hide the spinner
        hideSpinner();

        return error;
    });
}

ajax('example.com').then(function(response) {
    // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
    // show error
});
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I know that, but this involves putting showSpinner() and hideSpinner() with each AJAX call...

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, OP wants to hook the start and end of each fetch calls.

Comment: @JimArcher Indeed... Maybe wrap it in some function? And call that wrapper instead of fetch? I've changed example.

Comment: This is the right idea but @EtienneMartin nailed it!

Answer (score 2):

The main issue I have found using the setting manually a "loading" flag to 
true / false is that is quite easy to skip by mistake the set to false flag and your application would like hanged), and on the other hand I dont' want to mess up when several ajax request are being called in parallel, this comes even more harder when you want to track some of them, but in other cases you want to make silent requests.

I have created a microlibrary called react-promise-tracker to handle this in a more automatic way. How it works

Install promise tracker

```sh
npm install react-promise-tracker --save
```

Implement a simple loading indicator component (you can add the style you need for it), and wrap it with the *promiseTrackerHoc*

```
import { promiseTrackerHoc } from 'react-promise-tracker';

const InnerLoadingIndicator = props => (
   props.trackedPromiseInProgress &&
   <h1>Hey some async call in progress ! Add your styling here</h1>
);

export const LoadingIndicator = promiseTrackerHoc(InnerLoadingIndicator);
```

Instantiate it in your application root component:

```
render(
  <div>
    <App />
    <LoadingIndicator/>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Whenever you want to track a fetch or any promise based call (including async/await), just wrap it with the *react-promise-tracker* function *trackPromise*:

```
import { trackPromise } from 'react-promise-tracker';

export class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    trackPromise(
      userAPI.fetchUsers()
        .then((users) => {
          this.setState({
            users,
          })
        })
    );
  }

  // ...
}
```

More resources:
- Step by step tutorial (including adding a nice looking spinner): https://www.basefactor.com/react-how-to-display-a-loading-indicator-on-fetch-calls

- Live sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-promise-tracker-default-area-sample
- Github page: https://github.com/Lemoncode/react-promise-tracker

Answer (score 0):

What you can do when the `fetch` initially happens, you `setState` to loading as `true`. Then, once fetch is done, you can `setState` as loading is `false`. And you display the spinner based on the current state.

For example,

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { loading: false };
  }

  loadData(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    fetch(....).then( res => res.json()).then( resJson => {
      // do other stuff here.
      this.setState({ loading: false });    
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <DisplayComponent />
         <button onClick={this.loadData}>Click Me</button>
         { this.state.loading ? <Spinner /> : null }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can check out [react conditional rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html)